# Use a variable to sort by a key in a List<Map> instead of explicitly naming the key name

Tags: flutter, dart

This is probably very easily answered, but I got a little stumped. Couldn't find a reference this this kind of question anywhere, which seems amazing.

I have a `List<Map>` and I want to sort it by the key provided through a variable instead of explicitly naming the key to sort by.

Here is what I have:

```
      adminList.sort((a, b) => (b.sortField).compareTo(a.sortField));
```

AdminList is my `List<Attendee>` and a & b want my constructor (key) names ("firstName," "lastName," etc) and won't let me substitute a variable, as toString or anything I've tried.  I want to use sortName, which might be assigned as "firstName" now, "lastName" later.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  So technically, my named class was not a map, though it feels like one to this novice coder, and in order to access members by a string variable, I needed to create a toMap function within my class, call that, and reference my variable like so:

```
class AttendeeData {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
AttendeeData({this.firstName, this.lastName,});

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
 return {
  'firstName':firstName,
  'lastName:'lastName,};
}}
```

Now, I can define sortField, and filter by it.  Changing it to lastName whenever I want.

```
String sortField = 'firstName';

      adminList.sort(
      (a, b) => (a.toMap()[sortField]).compareTo(b.toMap()[sortField]));
```